# Low GPU utilization while training tensorflow model on A100 GPU on cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, training-data, tfrecord

This is the GPU utilization of my model while training on A100 GPU on cloud. What could be the possible bottleneck? I'm using tfrecord datasets of each 550MB. GPU memory usage is almost 100% all the time.

[image]

Comment: maybe it is not bottleneck - maybe this natural behavior for tensorflow. maybe in some moments it run calculations and it needs full GPU but in other moments it has to do other things (ie. select other batch) and this needs lestt GPU.